# Composer - Changing the version of PHP it uses in the env

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

So im trying to get my version of composer running on a different version of PHP

For instance, the server runs PHP 5.4, and i want it to run as 5.6 in a specific users directory

I have installed the composer.phar file into the root of a users directory as seen below

```
/home/myuser/composer.phar
```

Then i added alias's to the users .bashrc as follows

```
alias php='/usr/local/php56/bin/php'
alias composer='/usr/local/php56/bin/php /home/myuser/composer.phar'
```

When i run php -v as that user it returns the correct version of PHP ( 5.6 )

The problem is, that the first line of the composer.phar has the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Which makes it actually run as the original 5.4

Is there anything i can do about this? this is the last step in which i need to get my site working.

Also, i dont have the option to upgrade the default 5.4 version

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out.

I added the following code to my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php56/bin:$PATH
```

and then ran

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```